# Specifying null with nifi expression language

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to replace an empty field with nulls in an UpdateRecord processor.

```
/title    ${field.value:replaceEmpty(null)}
```

This fails because "null" is not a valid keyword.  How does one specify null in the nifi expression language?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use the `literal()` function to return a String value that is the exact input to the function, and you can nest that inside your `replaceEmpty` method. Try using the expression `${field.value:replaceEmpty(${literal('null')})}`.</strike>

If you are doing this in the `UpdateRecord` processor, you want to use [Apache NiFi RecordPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html) syntax, not [Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html). I believe the `CSVReader` and others parse even a field value containing only spaces to *empty*, so a regular expression like `replaceRegex( /title, '^(?![\s\S])$', 'null' )` doesn't work.

My suggestion would be to file a Jira requesting this capability. In the mean time, do not use `UpdateRecord` for this, but rather `ReplaceText` with a regular expression like `,\s?,` for an empty CSV value and replace it with `null`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick using `RecordPath`, if the field value is blank you can do this to get a null value.

- `/fieldName[not(isBlank(/fieldName))]`

Comment: I was trying to do the same as OP, and this answer worked great.

Answer (score 0):

It is giving answer as
{
"fieldname" : "null"
}

here null is a string not a null value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).